# А почему нет опросов на русском SO?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, опрос

Почему нет [таких](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019/) опросов на русском SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Overflow компания американская и в большей степени англоязычная. Существование версий SO на русском, португальском, испанском и японском можно считать своеобразным и пока что ещё долгоживущим экспериментом. Предложения о создании сайтов на других языках, или даже сайтов других тематик на поддерживаемых (с грехом пополам) языках автоматически блокируются (т.е. отклоняются). Неизвестно когда и изменится ли вообще эта политика. Понимая всё выше сказанное, ответ простой - русский язык на SO живёт стараниями энтузиастов, в компании нет ресурсов (по причине отсутствия конкретных активных планов по языкам, отличным от английского) проводить упомянутые опросы на других языках или хотя бы даже переводить текст уже проведённых опросов. Весь интерфейс сайта переводится энтузиастами (не стоит ровным счётом ничего для компании).

Comment: Почему тогда вообще дали добро на русский SO?

Comment: @doox911 в какой-то момент, видимо, хотели поработить мир нативными языками. Потом позиция изменилась.

Comment: @doox911 потому что это было давно, и тогда предложения для сайтов на других языках были разрешены. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Не совсем понял ваш комментарий. Что значит **"поработить мир нативными языками"**?

Comment: @doox911 сделать туеву хучу сайтов на движке SE по различным тематикам на множестве мировых языков.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а сейчас не туева хуча?)

Comment: После вашего ответа стало грустно.

Comment: @doox911 на английском много, на других языках - единицы. Несколько SO (4 штуки) и ещё ["Русский язык"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @doox911 SOru - это бывший хешкод. По сути, компания тогда купила аудиторию в надежде потом монетизировать.

Comment: @Suvitruf, я тогда не совсем понимаю в чём суть — прибыль компании?

Comment: @doox911 вместе с хешкодом куча пользователей пришло, которых можно монетизировать. Цель компании любой, очевидно, заработать денег, если отбросить все эти вещи про "базу знаний". Просто они недооценили масштаб немного и сейчас нет ресурсов на поддержку локализованных сайтов. Насколько я знаю, интернациональными сайтами только Николай занимается.

Comment: @Suvitruf, что у вас означает **хешкод** и кто такой **Николай**?

Comment: @doox911 до SOru был http://hashcode.ru, потом из него сделали https://ru.stackoverflow.com. Николай - комьюнити менеджер (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky).

Comment: @Suvitruf Спасибо)

Comment: @doox911 здесь можно почитать [про хэшкод](https://vc.ru/flood/1599-startap-set-znaniy-rossiyskiy-stack-exchange-na-samookupaemosti-i-bez-investorov) и про то, [как он стал русским Stackoverflow](https://vc.ru/story/11103-knowledge-network-stack-overflow).